# Apache Virtual Document Root "/sites/%-2.0.%-1/www"

Tags: macos, apache, virtualhost

Would anyone be able to give me an example of how this Apache directive, VirtualDocumentRoot "/sites/%-2.0.%-1/www" would resolve a request. I have read the docs and searched for examples but it still does not make any sense. Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this is a roundabout way of saying take the last two segments of the hostname.

The interpreted part is %-2.0.%-1

- %: begins the interpolation, that's easy.
- -: means go right-to-left counting which segment of the Hostname the next digit refers to
- 2: 2nd component of the Hostname
- The ".0" is kind of a hack to allow you to include a literal "." immediately after a %X
- .: literal "."
  %-1: The last component of the Hostname, e.g. com/net/org/biz/uk

So this entire expression just grabs the "last two" components of the hostname separated by a dot.

e.g. foo.example.com, www.example.com and example.com go to the same place on-disk.

Comment: A good way to test is just add %f to your LogFormat and look in the access log.  You can drive quick tests w/ different hostnames on the command line e.g.

printf "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: blarg.example.com\r\n\r\n" | nc 0 80